# Printing only specific bibliography categories

Tags: bibliographies, splitbib

I am about to write a 'PhD by publication'-type dissertation, which essentialy will have the following format:

1. Title page, abstracts, ToC, etc.
2. List of my 'main' publications (the ones on which the dissertation is based)
3. List of my other publications
4. Main description of the work
5. Bibliography (list of references by other authors)

Splitbib allows me to have three categories with different labels, which is exactly what I need, but my question is, how can I print these categories separately? I still want to cite all of them in point 4.

Answer (score 1):

You could use keywords. First you assign each entry a keyword, with the syntax e.g.

```
@book { firstbook,
    title = {Title of Book in Group 1},
    author = {Name Surname},
    keywords = {firstgroup}
}
```

Then you print the bibliography of each group, e.g.

```
\printbibliography[keyword=firstgroup,title={My First Group}]

\printbibliography[keyword=secondgroup,title={My Second Group}]
```

And you can issue another `\printbibliography` without options to print the whole bibliography.

See `biblatex` documentation for further details